# Cannot load css from assets

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

import "./assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./assets/css/stylesheet.css";
import "./assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/all.min.css";
import "./assets/vendor/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.css";
import "./assets/vendor/currency-flags/css/currency-flags.min.css";
import "./assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css";
import "./assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js";
import "./assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";
import "./assets/vendor/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js";
import "./assets/vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js";
import "./assets/js/theme.js";

class Header extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return <div className="header-column justify-content-start">
                        <div className="logo">
                            <a className="d-flex" href="index.html" title="Payyed - HTML Template"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Payyed" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header-nav"> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </button>
                        <nav className="primary-menu navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                            <div id="header-nav" className="collapse navbar-collapse">
                                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                    <li className="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li className="dropdown"> <a className="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Currency</a>
                                        <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="graph.html">Graphs</a></li>
                                            <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="table.html">Rates Table</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="landing-page-receive.html">API</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about-us.html">About</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="fees.html">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
    }
}

export default Header;
```

This is how my folder structure looks like
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN2WG.png)

My assets source link are correct but shows me this error
[Error Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDLda.png)

Why it keeps happening and are there any ways to fix this problem?

Thanks to listen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load explicitly from assets try `../../`.
eg : `import "../../assets/js/theme.js"`